# Get element underneath another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, detect

Just wondering the best way to tackle this.

Let's say I have a fixed navbar that sits exactly centered vertically.

As I'm scrolling, I want to find out the element behind the `nav` bar.

Lets say I have a nav like so:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#services"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And then sections like so:

```
<section id="about"></section>
<section id="services"></section>
<section id="contact"></section>
```

If I give them all a fixed height of say 1000px so that we are able to scroll properly, how can I detect when the navbar is say over the 'services' section, so I can append an active class etc.

I was going to detect the scroll position from the top of the document, and compare that to the top positions of the sections which I'd be able to find out where the navbar is located from there, but is this the best way to tackle this?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/c8jhajde/

Comment: Yes, that's the best way to tackle this.

Comment: Use the same approach as [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/9o7bfvzp/) fiddle. Just loop through the different DOM elements and attach an event handler than goes off when a given condition is true.